# Time Complexity of this nested for-loop algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having some trouble calculating the bigO of this algorithm:

```
public void foo(int[] arr){
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

I know the first for loop is O(n) time but I can't figure out what nested loop is. I was thinking O(logn) but I do not have solid reasoning. I'm sure I'm missing out on something pretty easy but some help would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Let's note `n` the length of the array.

If you consider the second loop alone, it is just a function `f(i)`, and since it will iterate on all elements from `i` to `1`, its complexity will be `O(i)`. Since you know that `j<n`, you can say that it is `O(n)`. However, there is no logarithm involved, since in the worst case, *i.e.* `j=n`, you will perfrom `n` iterations.

As for evaluating the complexity of both loops, observe that for each value of `i`, the second loop goes throught `i` iterations, so the total number of iterations is

```
1+2+...+(n-1)= n*(n-1)/2=(1/2)*(n^2-n)
```

which is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider `c` as a number of times `count` is incremented in the inner loop then the total number of times `count` is incremented can be represented by the formula below:

[image]

As you can see, the total time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n^2)`.